# SQL trying to separate entries values in a database field

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write some SQL code that will allow me to separate the individual values from this field in a database feed. I have tried a few different things and none are working properly and while I can get it to work via VBA or program it via another language I was wondering if there was a way to do it via SQL directly (with or without having to use a stored procedure).
Ideally I would like to be able to populate a table with the unique values only which would require having to check the values already stored in the destination table before inserting the new records however just being able to separate the values into individual entries would be good for now.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', vaccines) > 0
           THEN SUBSTRING(vaccines, 1, LEN(vaccines) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(vaccines)))
           ELSE ''
       END AS vax1,
        CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', vaccines) > 0
           THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(vaccines), 
                       1, 
                       CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(vaccines)) - 1))
        
           ELSE vaccines
       END AS vax2
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT vaccines FROM Covid_Vaccination_By_Country) AS Vax(vaccines);
```

However while this is splitting the first entry away reasonably well its not doing anything for subsequent values.

I was trying to come up with the simplest and smallest block of SQL to do this but no luck so far any ideas?

| vaccine |
| --- |
| Covaxin, Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| EpiVacCorona, Sputnik V |
| Johnson&Johnson |
| Johnson&Johnson, Moderna, Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sinopharm/Wuhan, Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sputnik V |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Beijing, Sinopharm/Wuhan, Sinovac |
| Sinovac |
| Sputnik V |

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: It seems you were looking to parse into columns.  If you have a known or maximum number of observations... take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cc68530265127465ddb20fe3fccb3211

Comment: Sorry I meant to mention that I was looking at SQL Server 18

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2016 and higher, you can use `string_split()` to get what you want. To remove spaces I have used `ltrim(rtrim(vaccine))`. If you are using SQL Server 2017 and higher then you can use `trim(vaccine)` instead.

Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE Covid_Vaccination_By_Country (vaccineS VARCHAR(500));

 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Covaxin, Oxford/AstraZeneca');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('EpiVacCorona, Sputnik V');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Johnson&Johnson');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Johnson&Johnson, Moderna, Pfizer/BioNTech');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sputnik V');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sinopharm/Wuhan, Sputnik V');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing, Sputnik V');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Oxford/AstraZeneca, Pfizer/BioNTech, Sputnik V');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Pfizer/BioNTech');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Pfizer/BioNTech, Sinopharm/Beijing');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Sinopharm/Beijing');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Sinopharm/Beijing, Sinopharm/Wuhan, Sinovac');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Sinovac');
 INSERT INTO Covid_Vaccination_By_Country VALUES('Sputnik V');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT
     LTRIM(RTRIM((value))) vaccine
 FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT vaccines 
      FROM Covid_Vaccination_By_Country) AS Vax(vaccines)
 CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT (vaccines, ',')
 GO
```

Output:

| vaccine |
| --- |
| Covaxin |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| EpiVacCorona |
| Sputnik V |
| Johnson&Johnson |
| Johnson&Johnson |
| Moderna |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Moderna |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Moderna |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Wuhan |
| Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sputnik V |
| Oxford/AstraZeneca |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Sputnik V |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Pfizer/BioNTech |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Beijing |
| Sinopharm/Wuhan |
| Sinovac |
| Sinovac |
| Sputnik V |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aebcf6598b76ae1ad369abcf5d960842)*

Comment: Thanks folks that works fine I had looked at String Split but never considered Cross Apply

Comment: You are most welcome @user2711259. Happy to help. Best wishes.